# RenderTarget2D moves with scene

Tags: xna, monogame, rendertargets

I encountered a strange RenderTarget issue, in XNA/Monogame.

I am currently updating my render target at every frame, just to test to see what is happening.  When I move the camera around, the positioning of the drawing inside of my rendertarget moves as well.

Notice in the example, how the image moves inside of my render target:
[image: Example]

Here is the code for the Render Target draw:

```
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(Render);
RoundLineManager.Draw(Branches.GetAllObjects(), new Color(102, 50, 18), Matrix.Identity * Camera.View * Camera.Projection, RoundLineManager.TechniqueNames[0]);
SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.BackToFront, null, null, null, null, null, Camera.View);

foreach (Pool<Leaf>.Node l in Leaves.ActiveNodes)
    if (l.Item.Visible)
        l.Item.Draw();

SpriteBatch.End();
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
```

Here is the related Camera properties:

```
public Matrix View
{
    get
    {
        return Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_pos.X, -_pos.Y, 0)) *
                Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) *
                Matrix.CreateScale(new Vector3(Zoom, Zoom, 1)) *
                Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(ViewportWidth * 0.5f + shakeOffset.X, ViewportHeight * 0.5f + shakeOffset.Y, 0));
    }
}

public Matrix Projection
{
    get
    {
        return Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, Infinidrill.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, Infinidrill.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was my View property of the Camera class that was causing it.  Really tired today, ugh.  Here is the updated code:

```
public Matrix View
{
    get
    {
        return Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width * 0.5f, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height * 0.5f, 0));
    }
}
```